# How to parallelize a for loop in python/pyspark (to potentially be run across multiple nodes on Amazon servers)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, parallel-processing, pyspark, mapreduce

Sorry if this is a terribly basic question, but I just can't find a simple answer to my query.

I have some computationally intensive code that's embarrassingly parallelizable. The pseudocode looks like this.

```
n = 500
rounds = 200

data = [d_1, ..., d_n]
values = [ 0 for _ in range(n) ]

for _ in range(rounds):
  for i in range(n): # Inner Loop
    values[i] = compute_stuff(data[i])
  data = special_function(values)
```

Each iteration of the inner loop takes 30 seconds, but they are completely independent. So I want to run the `n=500` iterations in parallel by splitting the computation across 500 separate nodes running on Amazon, cutting the run-time for the inner loop down to ~30 secs. How do I do this?

I'm assuming that PySpark is the standard framework one would use for this, and Amazon EMR is the relevant service that would enable me to run this across many nodes in parallel. So my question is: how should I augment the above code to be run on 500 parallel nodes on Amazon Servers using the PySpark framework? Or else, is there a different framework and/or Amazon service that I should be using to accomplish this?

Here are some details about the pseudocode. Each data entry `d_i` is a custom object, though it could be converted to (and restored from) 2 arrays of numbers `A` and `B` if necessary. The return value of `compute_stuff` (and hence, each entry of `values`) is also custom object. Although, again, this custom object can be converted to (and restored from) a dictionary of lists of numbers. Also, `compute_stuff` requires the use of PyTorch and NumPy. Finally, `special_function` isn't some simple thing like addition, so it can't really be used as the "reduce" part of vanilla map-reduce I think.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Based on your describtion I wouldn't use pyspark. To process your data with pyspark you have to rewrite your code completly (just to name a few things: usage of rdd's, usage of spark functions instead of python functions). 
I think it is much easier (in your case!) to use something like the wonderful [pymp](https://github.com/classner/pymp). You don't have to modify your code much:

```py
#still pseudocode
import pymp

n = 500
rounds = 200

data = [d_1, ..., d_n]
values = pymp.shared.list()

for _ in range(rounds):
  with pymp.Parallel(n) as p:
        for i in p.range(n):
            values.append(compute_stuff(data[i]))
  data = special_function(values)
```

In case the order of your `values` list is important, you can use `p.thread_num +i` to calculate distinctive indices. 
Pymp allows you to use all cores of your machine. When you want to use several aws machines, you should have a look at [slurm](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/deploying-a-burstable-and-event-driven-hpc-cluster-on-aws-using-slurm-part-1/).

Comment: Can pymp be used in AWS? say the sagemaker Jupiter notebook?

Comment: @thentangler Sorry, but I can't answer that question. I have never worked with Sagemaker. In case it is just a kind of a server, then yes.